# How to cache properly with Code Igniter and twig

Tags: json, codeigniter, caching, twig, apc

I'm using CodeIgniter + Twig and I need to cache some data.

It's data that don't need to be frequently modified/accessed and that need to be accessed only when modifying (as I'm caching a view of it every time I'm modifying it).

What is the best way to do that ?

- Save the data in a .json somewhere
- Save the data in json format in a table

Should I use APC or caching to disk? I feel like it doesn't need to be cached in the memory but I don't really get all this. Also is there a library to cache on disk or do I do it myself with file_put_contents

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to cache, the HTML output of your views or the data that you're passing to the views?

CodeIgniter has a caching driver with multiple adapters (APC, File, Memcached) that can easily be swapped whenever you need to do so. [Official docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html) should be enough to get you on your way.

There is also something called [output caching](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html) which caches the HTML output of the entire page.

Comment: the data. And it's changing regularly and is pretty big I don't think I want to store that in the memory.